I would like my autosort function to SKIP 2 sheets
I am using the code below to automatically create a new blank TEMPLATE sheet every time I add a person to my LIST sheet....
function TemplateDuplication()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
temp = ss.getSheetByName('TEMPLATE'),
all = ss.getSheetByName('LIST'),
sheets = ss.getSheets(),
vals = all.getRange('a:a').getValues();
for (var i = 0, len = sheets.length, names = []; i < len; i++)
names.push(sheets[i].getName());
for (var i = vals.length-1; i > 0; i--)
{
var name = vals[i][0];
if (name !='' && names.indexOf(name) == -1)
  {
temp.activate();
ss.duplicateActiveSheet()
    .setName(vals[i][0])

 }  }}

Then I use the code below here to sort the sheets so they stay alphabetical for my boss.
function onOpen()
{
sortSheetsByName();
}
function sortSheetsByName() {
var aSheets = new Array();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
for (var s in ss.getSheets())
{
aSheets.push(ss.getSheets()[s].getName());
}
if(aSheets.length)
{
aSheets.sort();
for (var i = 0; i < aSheets.length; i++)
{
var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName(aSheets[i]);
if(theSheet.getIndex() != i + 1)
{
ss.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1);
}
    }
  }
}

Now I ALMOST have it perfect. Is there a line of code (or lines) that I could insert into this second function that would have the alphabetization skip the TEMPLATE and LIST sheets (so they could stay at the front of the work book?)
I genuinely don't understand any of this coding, it does not resemble the QBasic or C++ that I have some familiarity with to my eyes. But I did get it to work with my workbook.
Any edit to the code I have made just results in loss of functionality.

Sorting Sheet Name and Prioritizing a certain Value upfront
Basically, what your code is doing is, it sorts using the name of the sheets. What I did is removed the TEMPLATE and LIST from the Array, and added them upfront to make sure that they are upfront. Using Concat and Filter Array Method.
Try this code:
function onOpen() {
  sortSheetsByName();
}

function sortSheetsByName() {
  var aSheets = new Array();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var s in ss.getSheets()) {
    aSheets.push(ss.getSheets()[s].getName());

  }
  if (aSheets.length) {
    aSheets.sort();
    var newListSheets = aSheets.filter(x => x != "TEMPLATE" && x != "LIST");
    var upfrontSheets = ["TEMPLATE", "LIST"];
    var updateList = upfrontSheets.concat(newListSheets)
    console.log(updateList)


    for (var i = 0; i < updateList.length; i++) {
      var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName(updateList[i]);
      if (theSheet.getIndex() != i + 1) {
        ss.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
        ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}

Sample Output


Reference:
Array Concat
Array Filter
